# Evaluate expressions in an array seqeuntially in PHP

Tags: php, arrays, for-loop

I have an array with say 10 different numerical values. Let's call this array `$values`. I have another array wit 10 different expressions. Let's call this array `$expression`.

I have to substitute each value in `$values` in each expression in `$expressions` one by one and check the final result. How can I do that?

Example values of values: `2, 8, 10, 9, 5` etc.
Example values of expressions: `5*$employees + 18` or `10*$days - 4`

When I loop over expressions, i want the $employees to have all values from 2, 8, 10, 9, 5 etc. Then I want $days to have all these values in next loop.

Here is my code so far:

```
function evaluate_everything($values, $expressions) {
    for($i = 0; $i < count($values); $i++) {
        foreach($expressions as $expression) {
            //Put value is expression.
        }
    }
    return true;
}
```

Comment: so what is the problem you cant replace variables with values or you cant generate all possible pairs of combinations of values to be replaced (or both)?

Comment: @NikosM. I am having trouble with "you cant replace variables with values". The loop I mentioned above will probably cover all possible combinations.

Comment: How will i store the expressions in an array? If I store it as a string, then how will I evaluate it?

Comment: This may help you: [Xpresion](https://github.com/foo123/Xpresion) (I am the author). It may save you some trouble defining and evaluating custom expressions. If you want something simpler and custom you can use anything you like, eg as strings and do replace and eval, as functions and so on..

Comment: Thanks @NikosM. Xpresion looks amazing. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following code works.  The PHP function eval() is used to evaluate a string as an expression:

```
function evaluate_everything($values, $expressions) {
    $output = [];
    foreach($expressions as $expression) {
        $row = [];
        foreach($values as $value){
            $str = '';
            eval("\$str = \"$expression\";");
            $result= eval('return '.$str.';');
            array_push($row, $result);
        }
        array_push($output, $row);
    }
    return $output;
}


$values = [1, 2, 3];

$expression1 = '5*$value + 18';
$expression2 = '10*$value - 4';
$expression3 = '$value + 42';
$expressions = [$expression1, $expression2, $expression3];

$resultArray = evaluate_everything($values, $expressions);

var_dump($resultArray);
```

Comment: why do we need to use two `eval()` here? :)

Comment: eval() is the thing that does the thing you're trying to do.  It takes the expression '5*$value + 18' when it is written as a string and evaluates as code.

Comment: In this case, you use it twice.  The first time eval("\$str = \"$expression\";"); writes a string with the value of $value in it.  The second evaluates that string as it were code.

Comment: using `eval()` is not dangerous if I have no use input right?

Comment: No, it's not exec(), which executes shell commands. As long as you are defining the expressions, not your users, you will be fine.

Comment: That said, you always need to sterilize any and all user inputs.  If your users are providing the $values, then you need to make sure they are numbers before you do anything with them.

Answer (score 2):

You can try using the `array_map` function and your expressions can be defined as functions:

```
function square($v) {
    return $v * $v;
}

function cube($v) {
    return $v * $v * $v;
}

function evaluate_everything($values, $expressions) {
    $results = [];

    foreach($values as $value) {
        foreach($expressions as $expression) {
            $results[] = array_map($expression, $value);
        }
    }

    return $results;
}

$vals1 = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5];
$values = [$vals1];
$expressions = ["square", "cube"];

$results = evaluate_everything($values, $expressions);

print_r($results);
```

Comment: Thanks @michael :). This works great without using `eval()`. However, I need to return `false` as soon as the expression equals a specific values like 0 or 10 etc.

Comment: I've updated the example to return the results. Do those specific values need to be excluded from the results? Maybe the results can be passed to a validation function?

Comment: Thanks @michael. I need to evaluate about 100 different such expressions in this situation. So, it will probably be easier to use `eval()` in this case. :)